# Search String in column value of Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to `search` a `String` in column of my table .The values are stored in 
column in this format

[image: Column Values]

My Search String is similar as above.  `i.e:`  comma separated `String`

My query is to find out whether any value in search String is present is my column or not.

Things I have Tried:

1. using `Like` : `Like` does it.But it matches individual values i.e for 3 search string values I have to make 15 like condition(costly for large table)

   `SELECT` * `from` A  `WHERE`  `mycol`  `LIKE` 'myval,%' `or` `mycol`  `LIKE` '%, `myval`,%' `or` `mycol`  `or`    `LIKE` '%, `myval`'
2. using `instr` function : `instr` matches the String but only the First Occurance.

   e.g: `select * from A where instr ('123' ,'12')`
3. using `In` : This donot `search` within the `String` .But Matches the values individually.
4. I have tried Like function Like(X , Y) from docs [Here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

So my Question is there a way , instead of Individually searching my `search` `string` in the column using `Like` Operator or `In` function . I could search my values values in single `query` something like combination of `In` and `Any`(not supported in `Sqlite`) `function` does in other `Db`

`i.e` `select * from A where Any('my search string') in ('my column value')`

Any Answer or comment is HIGHLY Appreciated.Hoping for reply.

Comment: Why does your app require multiple strings to be merged in a single value? Can you change the database structure?

Comment: @CL. Actually these are some Ids Which I want to find whether its is present in My table column & accordingly perform some actions if Matched.

Answer (score 2):

You have problems because your database is not properly normalized.

To have multiple search IDs for each `MyTable` row, create a second table that can have multiple rows, with one search ID in each row:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    MyTableID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    [...]
);
CREATE TABLE MyTableSearchIDs (
    MyTableID INTEGER REFERENCES MyTable(MyTableID),
    SearchID INTEGER  -- or TEXT or whatever
);
```

To search for a `MyTable` row, search its ID first:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTableID IN (SELECT MyTableID
                    FROM MyTableSearchIDs
                    WHERE SearchID = 'myvalue')
```

The same can be done with a join:

```
SELECT MyTable.*
FROM MyTable
JOIN MyTableSearchIDs USING (MyTableID)
WHERE MyTableSearchIDs.SearchID = 'myvalue'
```